# is there any-way to use SpannableString in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, text-size

I want to set the title of the TabLayout with two different text sizes. Like the given image below. Or the other way around to achieve this!

[image]

I have tried with SpannableString like give below. This snippet is in the for loop till 5!

```
SpannableString mSpannableString=  new SpannableString(s);
mSpannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,5, 0); // set size
mSpannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);// set color
mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setText(mSpannableString);
```

But as mentioned by CommonaSware **setText()** is not taking the rich content!

Comment: Perhaps you can do with fromHtml()

Comment: Use Html.fromHtml() or if it doesn't works then create a custom layout for the tab.

Comment: @SahilMunjal Html.fromHtml() no luck with this one too!

Comment: Then you should use custom layout for the tab..

Comment: `setText()` on a `TabLayout.Tab` takes a `CharSequence`. If rich formatting via a `SpannableString` does not work, that feels like a bug in `TabLayout`. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you attempted to set the text of the tabs.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the suggestion and yes it seems like the bug with TabLayout. I have edited my question though!

Comment: That code seems fine. You might create a sample project that reproduces the issue, then [file a bug report](http://b.android.com), as I do not see an existing bug report for this problem. Tactically, as Sahil suggests, you may be able to use a custom view for the tab contents.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just filed a bug to android. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: It's the `TextAppearance` style that's set by default on the tabs' `TextView`s that's causing that. If you don't want to use a custom `View` for the tabs, there's a way to set the `TextAppearance` on them that won't strip the spannable stuff.

Comment: @MikeM. First of all thanks for the suggesting the way around. But I am suspecting that with `TextAppearance` either I can set the Large font or Small font size. Mine need to have both it's like title & sub-title.

Comment: Nah, there's just a single attribute setting in the default `TextAppearance` style that causes the spannable info to be lost. If you use your own style with that set to `false`, your `SpannableString` will work as intended.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh is it? but actually I am not aware of that attribute. tell me if you know it so that i can give it a try! thanks

Comment: Sure. I'll post it when I get a chance here in a minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TabLayout`'s default style for its `TextView`s uses a `TextAppearance` with the `textAllCaps` attribute set to `true`. The transformation method for this handles the `CharSequence` as a flat `String`, so any `Spannable` info is lost.

To prevent this, we can create a style for the `TabLayout` that disables `textAllCaps`. For example:

```
<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Setting this as the `tabTextAppearance` on the `TabLayout` will allow your `SpannableString` to work as expected.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance" />
```

---

As mentioned in comments, using a custom `View` for the tabs is another option here, since that wouldn't have the problematic attribute setting by default.

Answer (score 2):

**Another approach is to use SpannableString text to TabLayout:**

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString( tabTitles[position]);
        sb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,5, 0); // set size
        sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);// set color

        return sb;
    }
```

For more information check [Add Icons+Text to TabLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-iconstext-to-tablayout)

Answer (score 0):

**Supplementary for Mike M. ´s Answer**

I had the same issue but only in Lollipop and backwards , in Oreo it worked just fine before getting styled, fortunatelly Mike's answer solved it.

I was using Google Material TabLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector_green">

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

At least, with this widget is not necessary to put styling if You are working for Oreo and on.