# 3 states TabLayout with 3 differents colors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm trying to have a tabLayout with 3 differents TextColor based on 3 states that I'll do programmatically, basically the states will be `CURRENT`, `SEEN`, `UNSEEN` and everything is dynamic.

The problem is that the base viewpager and more precisely tablayout allows only 2 states which are `SELECTED` and `UNSELECTED`. Not to mention the setCustomView, will add (create) a view instead of setting (update) the value and I end up stacking views...

I was thinking about overriding the TabLayout class or adding some kotlin extentions but dunno really where to start.

If you guys could point out some directions it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to change the tab items text color manually by setting text as a `SpannableString` and applying `ForegroundColorSpan`, See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40968375/10172915

Comment: This way I can make it work! Thx
But now the issue it that the setText remove the tabLayout animation, currently trying to find a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it worked thanks to @Akaki pointing me in the right direction:

First created a method to change tabTextColor:

```
private fun changeTabTextColor(tabLayout: TabLayout?, index: Int, mainColor: Boolean) {
    if (index in 0 until maxPosition) {
        val tab = tabLayout?.getTabAt(index)
        val sb = SpannableString(tab?.text)
        val color =
            if (mainColor) ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.main_text_color)
            else ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.secondary_text_color)
        sb.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, sb.length, 0)
        tab?.text = sb
    }
}
```

I'm handling 2 colors here, but can add more if needed.

Second the crucial part is that setting the text will destroy the animation, so we need to handle it by ourselves in the ViewPager:

```
binding.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}

        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            tabLayout?.setScrollPosition(position, positionOffset, false)
        }
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {}
    })
```

That way the animation will remain.

Then I played with `onTabSelected` and called the method `changeTabTextColor` to fit my needs.